# Hide/Retrieve HTML code in browser

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want hide code inside div tag so that view-> page source will not show it to users. 
I got some answers before its not clear:

```
<script>
//ajax call via jQuery/Prototype loading content into div below
    $.ajax({
        url: "somepage.php",
        data: 'yourParameters'
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#loadhtmlinviaAjax').show(); //toggle display status of this div as required
            $('#loadhtmlinviaAjax').html(data);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="loadhtmlinviaAjax" style="display: none;"></div>
```

can anyone explain with example how to implement it ?
Also Can anyone explain how to retrieve full implementation code hidden inside div tag programatically ? ( I can retrieve using F12 in chrome)

Comment: The best way is not to write the code. Because even the commented code can be seen in the source code of the browser

Comment: To retrieve code that is hidden in a div tag.
use
`$('#loadhtmlinviaAjax').html();`

Comment: Any code appended to the DOM after page load will not be visible in the source of the page, however it can be inspected at runtime using the DOMInspector and viewed then. Short answer, there is no way to hide any client side code you put online.

Comment: I am able to read the website code using python urlib and i get <div id="middlePane" class="middlePane"></div>  How can i read data inside this div ?

Comment: Else I am able to read the full DOM contents ( contents of div) in chrome developer mode( F12 inspect mode) but how to retrieve those contents programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done simply by adding the code via javascript or jQuery. The code added dynamically using the JS does not appear in the view source.

[View Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ru1kfmz3/embedded/result/)

View Source here : "view-source:https://fiddle.jshell.net/ru1kfmz3/show/light/"

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
var s = "<ul>";
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
s+= "<li> I am Element " + i + "</li>";
}
s+="</ul>";

$(".myDiv").append(s);
```

Comment: Thank you i am able to do it but how to retrieve the code programmatically from a website which shows only empty <div> tags with id on view->page source

Comment: use: $(".myDiv").html();

Note: this will work only after the code is appended. is used before, it will return blank.

Comment: Its returning blank but i can see many data inside it using inspect element in chrome. Is there any way to retrieve all data in inspect element using python?

Comment: It will give the code only after the content is appended. If used before.. it will give blank.

Comment: So how to retrieve code after contacting server using python

Comment: I am sorry pal, I have no idea about Python,